# Flutter - Animated text kit, how to stop animation, so it only fades in and shows the text, instead of fading in and out and gone?

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, package

So I installed an [animated text kit](https://pub.dev/packages/animated_text_kit) but I'm running into some issue that I can't solve it, the animation fades in, scales in, then fades out and scales out. I want it to just fade and scale in and stay there, how can I do this? (I tried googling around but without luck)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use that package to show widgets with fading and sliding effects, I recommend you to use the delayed_display package in it's place, import it into your project, wrap your widget with DelayedDisplay and customize it for your own
Ex :

```
DelayedDisplay(
delay: Duration(seconds: 1),
fadeIn: true,
slidingBeginOffset: Offset(0, -0.1),
child: Text("Hello"),
),
```